# Apache camel JPA component multiple consumer environment, consume same message

Tags: jpa, apache-camel, consumer, camel-jpa

I am using Apache camel JPA component as consumer. This consumer will be running in multi instance environment. Now I want to make sure consumer from each instance should not read same records, so that I don't end up processing same record twice.

I have tried to use following parameters:
consumeDelete=false - [As I don't want the record to be deleted.]
skipLockedEntity=true

My understanding is consumeLockEntity which has default value as true, should able to provide me the capability which I am looking for.

But I am ending up getting my record processed multiple time.

Any help with example will be much appreciated.